# Rcrawler package: ContentScraper Error

Tags: r, web-scraping

i've a problem with ContentScraper function of [Rcrawler](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcrawler/Rcrawler.pdf) package. I would like to extract from [this site](https://www.skyscanner.it/trasporti/voli/rome/lond/180201?adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=0&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false&ref=day-view#results) some information about time and airports of arrival and departure and also the price: (I took inspiration fom [this site](https://github.com/salimk/Rcrawler#3-crawl-and-scrape-data-from-a-website-pages))

```
MY_Data=ContentScraper(CssPatterns = c(".leg",".price"), ManyPerPattern = T, Url = "http://www.skyscanner.it/trasporti/voli/rome/lond/180201?adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=0&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false&ref=day-view#results")
```

but i get this error:

```
Error in LinkExtractor(url = Ur, encod = encod) : object 'Extlinks' not found
```

I had a look to LinkExtractor function but i have no ideas of why it doesn't find Extlinks since it should be created by the function itself. Isn't it? 
Someone could help me?

Thank You!

Comment: What you are doing is asking others to engage in unethical activities with potential civil or criminal penalties (numerous international cases involving those happened in 2017). You should at least have the courtesy to mention that in your question. Your needs aren't greater than the site's policies despite how "stubborn" you are.

Comment: ok, i'm sorry i admit i'm not completely conscious of policies and penalties connected to web-scraping. After all i was just triing to retrieve one week time series for a class-exercise in an efficient way. I didn't have any criminal or commercial purpose, however i understood your reprimand , i 'll be more carefull. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

**This website doesn't allow scraping**. This may be one reason why your example doesn't work. You can try [in this web](http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html). I also recommend you to try `rvest` package which is easier to use.

Comment: Ahah i'm sorry but i'm stubborn.. So the problem is definitevely the site. I don't have any chance to get data from skyscanner whth any r package or application. True?

Comment: I'm not very familiar trying to extract data from skyscanner; maybe you can try with the link below, but I don't know how works. Hope that helps! https://partners.skyscanner.net/affiliates/travel-apis/

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same request using Rcrawler+phantomjs web driver but no result, There is some sort of javascript protection against unreal sessions,

```
br<-run_browser()
MY_Data<-ContentScraper(CssPatterns = c(".leg",".price"), ManyPerPattern = T, Url = "https://www.skyscanner.it/trasporti/voli/rome/lond/?adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=0&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false&ref=day-view&oym=1903&selectedoday=01", browser = br, RenderingDelay = 5)
```

I retrieved the session Screenshot, and I can confirm that the javascript which load results is stuck .

Using Rselenium+ chrome headless (with gpu enabled) I got robot check page. (see images)

As a result the only hope to get data legitimately is to use their API

[image]
[image: syscanner robot check]

Rcrawler creator